# application slow on iphone with phonegap

Tags: iphone, css, html, cordova

We testing our app on simulater is fast but slow on iphone.
We are initializing canvas for drawing and try to draw multiple line on the canvas is very slow.

Answer (score 2):

The simulator runs using the full power of the machine it is running on, it is not an emulator. That's why you can't trust it all the way through a project - every app **must** be test run on an actual device.

Although this isn't what you have asked for: Don't use phonegap. Please. It employs web technology to make development easier, but web technology is just not as performant as a native application would be. If you need to do extensive graphics operations, consider developing a native app.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion but i want to know that we are developing a application in HTML5 using phonegap and this code can be run on iphone and android as well. Is there any framework which can provide single time efforts programming and run on multiple devices ?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from not actually asking a question, you need to consider that the iphone has a much slower processor than what ever you're running the simulator on.